# Make grid area prefer to shrink

Tags: css, css-grid

I want left column to define the height of the block. The *middle* area of the right column should be:

- if the first column is longer: as small as possible to make the second column having the same height as first one, but not longer then area content and not shorter then 40px.
- otherwise: 40px long.

All conditions are written as the text of the areas in the following snippet:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto min-content 1fr / 1fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

section {
  background: silver;
}

.left {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

.middle {
  background: antiquewhite;
  min-height: 40px;
  max-height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
0. Grid does not have a fixed height.
<main>
  <section contenteditable class="left">
    1. The left column should determine the preferred size of the grid.
    If the right column can fit this height it should not make grid grow any further.
  </section>
  <section contenteditable>
    2. The top area should show all its content without additional space.
  </section>
  <section contenteditable class="middle">
    3. The middle area is a problem.<br>
    It should be strictly between top and bottom areas with gaps equal to grid-gap.
    Its height should be limited by 40px as minimum and its contents as maximum.
    The height is determined by the left column - it should never exceed height of contents and should be <em>as small as needed</em> to make columns having the same height.
    Content that doesn't fit into the area should be cropped (overflow: hidden).
  </section>
  <section contenteditable>
    4. The bottom area should follow the middle one without extra space between them (except grid-gap) and may (or may not - irrelevant) have some free space in the bottom if the left column is longer.
  </section>
</main>
5. Content placed in normal flow should follow bottommost point of the grid regardless witch column contains longer content.
```

## Here is some examples

(content of the right areas is never changed)

### Left column is short:

> [image: Example 1 - wrong]

> [image: Example 1 - right]

### Left column is long and middle area has enough content to fit the gap:

> [image: Example 2 - wrong 1]

> [image: Example 2 - wrong 2]

> [image: Example 2 - right]

### Left column is very long and can't be covered by middle cell contents

> [image: Example 3 - wrong]

> [image: Example 3 - right 1]

> [image: Example 3 - right 2]

## Some notes

I would like to do it by css only without scripts (I understand that I can add ResizeObserver and handle left area height changes).

I can solve the same problem for the case when adjustable cell it the bottom one, but this solution can't be applied for the middle one:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto 1fr / 1fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

section {
  background: silver;
}

.left {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
0. Grid does not have a fixed height.
<main>
  <section contenteditable class="left">
    1. The left column should determine the preferred size of the grid.
    If the right column can fit this height it should not make grid grow any further.
  </section>
  <section contenteditable>
    2. The top area should show all its content without additional space.
  </section>
  <div class="middle">
    <div contenteditable class="inner">
      There is no bottom cell. There is no bottom cell.
      There is no bottom cell. There is no bottom cell.
      There is no bottom cell. There is no bottom cell.
      There is no bottom cell. There is no bottom cell.
      There is no bottom cell. There is no bottom cell.
      There is no bottom cell. There is no bottom cell.
      There is no bottom cell. There is no bottom cell.
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
5. Content placed in normal flow should follow bottommost point of the grid regardless witch column contains longer content.
```

Comment: @Paulie_D, absolutely not related. There is no 2-dimentional layout and nothing about which element should grow. And also I can make elements with the same height, but in my question the second column can be larger then the first and without this condition I can solve too. And I even can solve without 5th condition about normal flow.

Comment: Nicely formulated question +1. Alas, still not entirely clear to me (although I don't think that's your fault). Does switching the second row from `min-content` to  `minmax(40px, 1fr)` get us any closer to a solution? https://jsfiddle.net/3vc4xo5e/1/

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin, seems it's not closer. See no fixes in comparison to my version and see additional problem with bottom space: https://i.stack.imgur.com/onWc7.png.

Comment: I don't think this is solvable by CSS-Grid alone. It seems to me that this requires a combination of Grid and Flexbox (with a structure change) but I'm interested to see what happens.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin, when the grid height is not specified, browser tries to fit all content and doesn't want to crop an element that it can fit. The possible solution was to get element out of the layout by position, but I see no way to use it as a base for the bottom element in that case. The other way is to place nested grid into the second column with fixing its height and make it absolute - then column is aligned right, but if it is longer, than the base one, overflow occurs and content covers following content in normal flow (so added point 5 into the question).

Comment: @Paulie_D, actually it's ok to change html.

Comment: So something like this...as a starting point - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MWmBzmG

Comment: @Paulie_D, https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqpHS.png.

Comment: I didn't say it was a complete solution just a starting point. I'm sure you can tweak the internals of the right side to meet your criteria.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I can solve only if _I break any single of these points:_ 1. Middle should shrink. 2. Middle should grow. 3. Middle has no empty space. 4. Root has no fixed height. 5. All construction should work in normal flow.

Comment: That should tell you something....it's quite possible that not all of your criteria can be met.

Comment: @Paulie_D, that's why I asked this question ;) Maybe I just don't know something useful.

Comment: the "impossible requirement" for me is the (3) Middle has no empty space. I don't think there is a way to express a max-height to prevent empty space (we have a complex cyclic calculation)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I can do 1-3, but only in price of loosing 5 when the left column is shorter (https://jsfiddle.net/5x3c97oy/) or 4 (add height to code in the question). If it is possible to fix the size of `right-inner` without using `position: absolute`, it would be a solution. Even if overflow (without positioning) exists, it is fixable by wrapping the whole thing into table-cell.

Comment: that's the issue, in your case you want right to depend on left and at the same time left on right if the latter is taller so it's a bit difficult for the browser to handle this and consider that the middle one should have a limit ... well, maybe someone will come with a solution ;) (actually I don't see a clear one, maybe will retry later)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, actually I want container depend on both left and right. But left can be smaller then total height, it's irrelevant like on the last screenshot with empty space on the right side.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, seems like I'm wrong about overflow. `contain: size` can replace `position: absolute`, but I failed to fit it into normal flow. https://jsfiddle.net/nxy561ze/. Asked in a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68642587/4928642. I thought it was possible by wrapping into table-cell, but it doesn't work.