# Fit an overflow into parent container

Tags: css, overflow

In the following example `div` is larger then `section` so the `section` has a visible overflow. I want `main` to expand and take this overflow so that the text bellow `main` won't be overlapped. But the size of the section should be kept the same.

```css
main {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

section {
  width: 8em;
  height: 4em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam quos amet impedit esse veritatis quia omnis.</div>
  </section>
</main>
Some text goes here and gets crossed by an overflow.
```

Searching for css-only solution replacement of this script:

```js
var main = document.querySelector('main')

var sectionBB = document.querySelector('section').getBoundingClientRect()
var divBB = document.querySelector('div').getBoundingClientRect()

main.style.minHeight = divBB.bottom - sectionBB.top + 'px'
```

```css
main {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

section {
  width: 8em;
  height: 4em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam quos amet impedit esse veritatis quia omnis.</div>
  </section>
</main>
Some text goes here and gets crossed by an overflow.
```

If you want the full problem, it's needed for one of the incomplete solutions of [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/68639486/4928642) which is here: https://jsfiddle.net/nxy561ze/.

Comment: Why not set your section height to auto?

Comment: @dalelandry, because it is a synthetic example, and in jsfiddle code I intentionally ask browser to ignore contents size to make middle (antiquewhite) block's size follow the left column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

float can help here but I don't think it will help you with your other question:

```css
main {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  overflow:auto;
  
}

section {
  width: 8em;
  height: 4em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: blue;
}
section div {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam quos amet impedit esse veritatis quia omnis.</div>
  </section>
</main>
Some text goes here and gets crossed by an overflow.
```

Comment: Nice, but I would agree that I don't know how to apply float there... Will wait a bit for alternative solutions and will accept this answer if there is no.

Comment: @Qwertiy you cannot because float won't work inside grid or flexbox, even inside a grid item of flex item it will do nothing because the items create BFC.

Comment: I thought about making the whole layout on floats, but I don't think I can synchronize their heights.

Comment: @Qwertiy and it will be a pain to deal with gaps and width since you don't have template-columns and gap when dealing with float.

Comment: Gaps can be made by margings. Or even paddings if add one more level of wrappers. But same heights seems impossible on floats.